# Lazyload and isotope masonry issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

Having an issue with isotope and lazyload. Seems to grid up isotope and each image with fixed height and width, it overrides the masonry layout. Maybe a CSS issue, but very confused as to what is happening. Here is my breakdown and screenshot:

HTML/PHP (I've shortened this is main elements of the code):

```
<div class="isotope">
<img class="lazy" data-original="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['url']) ?>" />
</div>
```

My css:

```
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope img {
    margin:0 8px 8px 0;
    width:202px;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Jquery:

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.isotope');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });
```

Lazy Load:

```
$(".lazy").lazyload();
```

Here is a screenshot so you can see lazyload making masonry a fixed grid, instead of it looking like this, it should be masonry and fit accordingly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify images `height` and `width` attributes, so the layout is correctly setup even though the images aren't loaded.

Otherwise, you could call a [`reLayout`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout) each time an image fire a `load` event, but this is far from ideal and performance expensive.

Comment: specifying height and width though will distraught the images that have a longer width then height. Using CSS i can simply specify the width: and it will automatically define height allowing me masonry. However when specifying height it squares off the images which i don't want..

Comment: You'd need to set each images **real** width/height, then use CSS to scale them to their final size. If there's no width/height, the browser don't know the size the element take before the image is completly loaded. So using lazyload break Isotope as it can't determine the size the images will have once loaded.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I've been able to define the width and height of the images, however when setting the width in CSS i am still getting distraught images. Any suggestions? thanks again man.

Comment: You'll need to add `height: auto;` when you set `width: 100%` on your `img`.